# jquery window location not work inside php echo?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

jquery window location is not work inside the php echo statement, is there any wrong in my code?

this is my code:

```
<?php
include "connection/db_connection.php";
$error=''; 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{ 
$sno=$_POST['sno'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$country=$_POST['s2'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['pwfield'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$state=$_POST['state']; 

$sql2="select email from login_warehouse WHERE email='".$email."' AND sno!='".$sno."'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
if(mysql_fetch_array($result2)>= 1) 
{

    $error= "Entered E-Mail ID Already in Exists!<br/>";
}
else
{
    $sql=mysql_query("update `login_warehouse` set name='".$name."', username='".$username."', password='".$password."', email='".$email."',address='".$address."',city='".$city."',state='".$state."', country='".$country."' where sno='".$sno."'");
    if($sql)
    {
        echo '<script>
        $(window).load(function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "edit_userprofile.php";
        }, 900)
        }); 
        </script>';
       $error='Admin details updated successfully!';            
  }
else
{

$error="Customer Already Exists";
}       
}
}
?>
```

what i wrote wrong in echo statement? or any other way is there to reload the page if the condition is true.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't relocate via php?

Comment: check in console of firebug or chrome for any error?

Comment: try using alert first to verify.

Comment: why don't you use PHP `header()` function for redirect ?

Comment: I've tried it out and the problem is not from the jquery. It comes from the php execution (checkalso jquery reference), you should change your script into pdo for everything better you will get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use jQuery/javascript , make sure you include jQuery library before Any jQuery code . If your posted code is the Starting code `Before HTML` , make sure you include js library first.

I would say if you use jquery to redirect , you will need DOM to be loaded (it will take a few seconds), window to be loaded , if you use `php header()` you will get redirected `Instantly`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in your `Javascript`. Check where your query is executing successfully.

Why don't you use PHP's `header()` to redirect the page.

```
if($sql)
{
   header("location:edit_userprofile.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery code, you must include the jQuery library file before the jQuery code executes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP **header()** to redirect to page you want like below:

```
if($sql)
{
    header("location:edit_userprofile.php");
}
```

Comment: ok, but i want to display successful message and after 10 seconds the page will redirect or reload the same page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<?php
include "connection/db_connection.php";
$error=''; 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{ 
$sno=$_POST['sno'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$country=$_POST['s2'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['pwfield'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$state=$_POST['state']; 

$sql2="select email from login_warehouse WHERE email='".$email."' AND     sno!='".$sno."'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
if(mysql_fetch_array($result2)>= 1) 
{

$error= "Entered E-Mail ID Already in Exists!<br/>";
}
else
{
$sql=mysql_query("update `login_warehouse` set name='".$name."', username='".$username."', password='".$password."', email='".$email."',address='".$address."',city='".$city."',state='".$state."', country='".$country."' where sno='".$sno."'");
if($sql)
{
    echo '<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = "edit_userprofile.php";
    }, 900)
    }); 
    </script>';
   $error='Admin details updated successfully!';            
  }
else
{

$error="Customer Already Exists";
}       
}
}
?>
```